# Passing parameters struct to function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, parameter-passing

I am System Analyst & Developer student, I'm trying to write code but I'm stuck, structs and fuctions are easy to understand but working with both together... is a... crap...

What an I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

typedef struct mercearia
{
    char mercadoria[20];
    int quantidade;
    int valor;

} mercearia;

void EstruturaCadastro(struct mercearia *m)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");

        setbuf(NULL, stdin);
        printf("Insira nome do produto a cadastrar: ");
        scanf("%s", &(*m)[i].mercadoria);

        setbuf(NULL, stdin);
        printf("Insira a quantidade do produto: ");
        scanf("%i", &(*m)[i].quantidade);

        setbuf(NULL, stdin);
        printf("Insira o valor do produto: R$ ");
        scanf("%i", &(*m)[i].valor);
    }
}
    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        struct mercearia m[5];
        EstruturaCadastro(&m);
    }
```

It gives me huge error list. Then I wrote same code but without creating array of struct and the code worked perfectly. I am missing up something.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

typedef struct mercearia
{
    char mercadoria[20];
    int quantidade;
    int valor;

} mercearia;


void EstruturaCadastro(struct mercearia *x)
{
    printf("\n");

    printf("Insira nome do produto: ");
    scanf("%s", &(*x).mercadoria);setbuf(NULL, stdin);

    printf("Insira a quantidade do produto: ");
    scanf("%i", &(*x).quantidade);setbuf(NULL, stdin);

    printf("Insira o valor do produto: R$ ");
    scanf("%i", &(*x).valor);setbuf(NULL, stdin);
}

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        struct mercearia produto;

        EstruturaCadastro(&produto);
    }
```

Comment: I never trust myself with operator precedences and would use `()` much more generously here: `&(*m)[i].mercadoria`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with structs and everything to do with how you're passing arrays to functions. For that code to work, the parameter should be declared as `mercearia (*m)[5]`.

Comment: You might want to take the guided [tour]. It is pittoresque.

Comment: You can use `m[i]` instead of `&(*m)[i]` for the `mercadoria` field, and `&m[i]` instead of `&(*m)[i]` for the other two fields.

Comment: Alternatively, you can change the function argument instead of the parameter type.   Pass `m` instead of `&m` in your first version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the 2nd example (simple) before trying the 1st (harder)

```
void EstruturaCadastro(struct mercearia *x)
{
    printf("\n");

    printf("Insira nome do produto: ");
    scanf("%s", x->mercadoria);

    printf("Insira a quantidade do produto: ");
    scanf("%i", &x->quantidade);

    printf("Insira o valor do produto: R$ ");
    scanf("%i", &x->valor);
}
```

No need for the `setbuf()` call, you flush stdin when you press the  key

Once you've done this, you can change to `m[i]->mercadoria`, etc in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of wrong with your original function. You're passing it a pointer to `struct mercearia` which is fine for passing in your array. Inside the function you can treat `m` the same way you would an array, so for example `m[0].valor` is how you'd access the `valor` value for the first element.

This means that your various calls to `scanf` become

```
    scanf("%s", m[i].mercadoria);
    scanf("%i", &m[i].quantidade);
    scanf("%i", &m[i].valor);
```

Note, that for reading in a string unlike other data types, you don't need to pass in the pointer to the string so you don't need the preceeding `&`.